# Optimal way to run a function on all rows of a Polar DF

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm applying a relatively complex function over a moderate  data-frame around 5k rows however it takes a long time ~10 mins and the different cores are only running at around 30% loading

How could I minimize the running time and ensure a 100% loading of all the CPU cores?

Is that way of calling the function and packing / unpacking the results the most appropriate?

```
class my_class():
   def __init__(self, bla:float=np.nan):
      pass

   def my_complex_function(self, param_A:float=np.nan, ...):
      bla bla
      return {f"{prefix_name}_result_A":result_A,
              f"{prefix_name}_result_B":result_B,
              f"{prefix_name}_result_B":result_C,
              ... }

my_object     = my_class(999.9)
float_param_D = 999.9
float_param_E = 999.9
float_param_F = 999.9
prefix_name   = "column_name_prefix"

df = df.with_columns([pl.struct(['float_param_A', 
                                 'float_param_B', 
                                 'float_param_C'] ).apply(lambda x: 
                      my_object.my_complex_function(
                              param_A      =x['float_param_A'], 
                              param_B      =x['float_param_B'], 
                              param_C      =x['float_param_C'], 
                              param_E      =float_param_E, 
                              param_F      =float_param_F, 
                              param_D      =float_param_D, 
                              float_param_G=0, 
                              prefix_name  =prefix_name ) 
                     ).alias('calculation_results')]
                     ).unnest('calculation_results')
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of polars? `.apply()` analysis was just added, `PolarsInefficientApplyWarning` messages should be generated if your function uses functionality that can be implemented natively in Polars expressions. As for the struct and dict unpacking, that seems to be the recommended way.

Comment: If you want 100% CPU utilization, you shouldn't write a complex python function. Python has the GIL so it will always use a single thread.

Try to do as much as possible in polars expressions.

And if you have to use python functions, then at least run them vectorized (i.e. use `map` instead `apply` in this case)

Comment: If you're using apply then there's nothing polars can do for you. You either need to figure out how to make your complex function into expressions so that you're not using apply OR you need to use multiprocessing outside of polars. You can't mix python's multiprocessing with polars though.

Answer (score 2):

Since your UDF is in Python and is CPU-bound, neither Polars vectorization nor multi-threading will help. There is a way to use multi-processing: You can use `.map(..)` instead of `.apply(...)`. Your UDF will be passed the entire column / Series, and computing the returned series is then under your control. Below I use the `unsync` library on `my_complex_function`, and a `parallel_wrapper`:

```py
@unsync.unsync(cpu_bound=true)
def my_complex_function(...)
   ... unchanged
   return 42

def parallel_wrapper(series):
    sub_procs = [my_complex_function() for i in range(len(series))]
    results = [sub.result() for sub in sub_procs]
    return pl.Series(series.name, results)
```

`parallel_wrapper` launches `N x my_complex_function`, gathers their `future` handles, then gather their `.result()`s to return as a series.

```py
mapped = df.select(pl.col('a').map(parallel_wrapper))
```

This should max out your cores. Overhead is sub-process + a Python interpreter running on each. Worth a try.